# Cell automatic selection in tableVIew using swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I have a table with about 40 records. I want to always select the cell that is in the center of the screen, in a certain position. Whenever I do the scrool from the table, it should change the selected row to the one that is currently in the center.
It would be the same as a picker but the row has several images and labels so it will not be possible to make a Picker.

Is it possible to do something similar?

Comment: May be you should use UICollectionView instead of UITableView. With collectionView you will have more freedom to display your cells.

Answer (score 2):

This **is** possible with a UIPickerView, and it does sound like that's what you're trying to recreate.

All you need to do is replace the view in the UIPickerView.  There are two methods you need which aren't normally required - you need to specify the height, and you need to define the view to be used for the row

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat 
{
    return self.myRowHeight
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView 
{
    var myView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.bounds.width, self.myRowHeight))
    // define & add whatever controls you need   
    myView.addSubview(myControl1)
    myView.addSubview(myControl2)

    return myView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, but it sounds like a bad user interface.

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollview. You could set yourself up as the scroll view delegate, and in response to delegate calls like `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` and/or `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_:)`, change the selection.

However I think you'd have a better user experience if you used a picker view. You can set up picker views to use a view for each index, so you should be able to serve up a custom view that contains multiple image views and labels as subviews.

Comment: but using a picker can I separate components in sections?

Comment: Picker views support multiple components, yes. Each component scrolls separately. Is that what you want?

Comment: if you split into components, then each component will be independently selectable - which doesn't sound like what you need.